# Sorting Difficulty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I have a bunch of objects, lets call them `Items`, each `Item` has, among other things, a `weight` and a `publisher`. I want to sort them by `weight` (decreasing), but, and here's the tricky bit, ensure that no `Items` with the same `publisher` appear twice (or more) in a row.

I was thinking about using a `sort_by` loop and keeping track of the publisher indexes along the way (with a hash using the publishers as the keys and arrays of indexes as values), but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about this or how to take care of that in practice if it is the best way. Any suggestions?

EX:

say all theses items were in an array called `items` and ordered randomly. I would like to sort them so the weight=2 items appear first and the items with 'foo' as the publisher don't appear next to each other if possible (if there were no other publishers in that weight class then they would appear next to each other)

```
items = [(id: 1, name: "item1", publisher: "foo", weight: 2),
    (id: 2, name: "item2", publisher: "foo", weight: 2),
    (id: 3, name: "item3", publisher: "baz", weight: 1),
    (id: 4, name: "item4", publisher: "bar", weight: 2)]

puts custom_sorting_method(items)
```

would return

```
   [(id: 1, name: "item1", publisher: "foo", weight: 2),
    (id: 4, name: "item4", publisher: "bar", weight: 2),
    (id: 2, name: "item2", publisher: "foo", weight: 2),
    (id: 3, name: "item3", publisher: "baz", weight: 1)]
```

Comment: What's your strategy if there are multiple `Item` with same `publisher`? Random pick one or any logic there?

Comment: There are, that's the case I'm asking about. I don't want `Items` with the same `publisher` to be displayed adjacently but I'm not sure how to take care of that

Comment: Please edit to provide an example and expected result.  Presumably, `items` is a hash whose keys are strings or symbols and whose values are either two-element arrays containing weight and publisher (e.g., `[1.2, "Random House"]`) or hashes (e.g., `{ :weight=>1.2, :publisher=>"Random House" }`). Be sure to assign the hash to a variable (e.g., `items = { 'Lord of the Rings'=>{ :weight=>1.2, :publisher=>"Random House" }, ... }`), so that readers can refer to the variable (`items`) in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: If the seven items with lowest weight were all by the same publisher, how would you expect that to appear in the data?

Comment: Answers might be more helpful if you could explain why items with the same publisher should not be adjacent. If, for example, you are ordering books from publishers, might it be more useful to construct a hash whose keys are publishers and whose values are arrays of books ordered by weight?

Comment: I'm making a service that combines a bunch of RSS feeds into one. Each `Feed` will have many `Stories`. I'm trying to make sure when I send my data to the user they don't see all the `Stories` from one `Feed` at the same time

Comment: You should think of each Item as an ActiveRecord object

Comment: You should make the input for your example a valid Ruby object, so readers can cut and paste (e.g., `Items = [(id: 1, name: "item1", publisher: "foo", weight: 2), (id: 2,...),...]`). You should be aware that some readers will downvote questions with examples that do not contain valid Ruby objects. `Items` is a constant since it begins with a capital letter. If you want it to be a variable, use `items = [...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try grouping by weight and sort each grouped list by publisher, followed by alternatively taking the first and last element of each sorted list.  Very roughly:

```
results = []
alt_methods = [:shift, :pop]

grouped = items.group_by{ |item| item[:weight] }
grouped_and_sorted = grouped.each do |k,v|
  v.sort_by { |item| item[:publisher] }
end

grouped_and_sorted.each do |k,v|
  v.length.times{ |i| results << v.send(alt_methods[i%2]) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will I have yet to test it out but I'll give it a try shortly

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are absolutely right.  Edited accordingly :)

Comment: Had to add an additional `items.sort_by! {|item| -item["weight"]}` to make sure the grouping was in order but great stuff otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted = Items.sort{|x,y| y.weight <=> x.weight}
sorted.uniq!{|x| x.publisher}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I believe the second line will actually delete the `Items` with duplicate `publishers`. I want to keep them just make sure they're not being displayed next to each other

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# Sorts by weight, and then distributes by publisher within each weight.
#
# @param [Array<Hash>] items
# @return [Array<Hash>]
def special_sort(items)
  by_weight_nested = Hash[
    items
      .group_by { |item| item[:weight] }
      .map { |weight, arr| [weight, arr.group_by { |item| item[:publisher] }] }
  ]

  sorted = []

  by_weight_nested.keys.sort.reverse.each do |weight|
    publishers = by_weight_nested[weight].keys
    0.upto(by_weight_nested[weight].values.map(&:size).max - 1) do |i|
      publishers.each do |publisher|
        sorted << by_weight_nested[weight][publisher][i]
      end
    end
  end

  sorted.compact
end
```